# How can I figure out what "changes" will a software make to my Win10?

Tags: windows-10

As is often notified:

```
Do you want this app to make changes to your device?
```

Is there a way to find the "changes" before I install the software? (e.g. add registry item, modify system settings, etc.)

## It would be great if we have

**app-specific control** (like Android)

It seems that Win10 only provided a privilege administration based on "user account". While app-specific control would be useful.

I do not believe apps. Some widely installed softwares(so they are necessities somehow) have been reported to steal user data or modify users' private files.

So it would be great if I can determine which apps can do what, e.g. "you can't read files from my D drive" or "you can only write files under your installation path":). Of course, this may beyond the control of the system so new protocol or guidelines for app development may be needed.

**app-specific record**

Concrete implementations may be various. E.g. it can be simply done by "put all app settings under its installation directory".
This means, when we remove a software, we can eliminate all footprints in system.

## About uninstall tools

I know uninstall tools and they're something like "data recover tool" - they don't know which apps （or system） changed what, so they simply recorded "what was changed after the installation of an app".

So using them may be dangerous if multiple apps are working together. (Some people reported such tools broken their system..)

Comment: There are likely a few ways to figure this out, but whether they're efficient or not is a different story. I know capturing a `base.wim` via `Dism` prior to installing the software and appending an image to `base.wim` after the install, then reviewing the WIM manifest database afterward would show all changed files after the initial capture of `base.wim`. PowerShell can list all files modified after a specified time, outputting to a file, but this wouldn't list changes to the Registry hives, nor would capturing a WIM _(export all hives before and after, then do a diff compare)_

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.

The message basically means that the program attempts to perform an administrative task and failed, thus needs administrative privileges. This can include writing to a location your user does not have write privileges to, but it can be more. What this is, can't be checked on beforehand.

You can create a shielded environment and run the app then and monitor what it changes, but at that point you are already doing exactly that what you wanted to prevent, so technically its not possible.

Although a software installation will always do the same thing, programs can also require administrative privileges when run and they can do different things depending on what actions you do.

The best thing you can do if safety is really a concern, is to use good uninstall software. Some of them come with an install monitor program to register all changes and log those to a logfile. IOBit uninstaller is such program, but there are others that can do this too.

An example of where this "Do you want this app to make changes to your device" can make a difference.

TeamViewer Quick Support will ask this question when you start it. If you click yes, the program is run as administrator. If you click no, the program is run as user.

If someone then remotes into your computer, depending whether you clicked yes or no, they will be able to do everything or are limited. When TeamViewer is not run as administrator, it cannot access the administrative runtime at all, meaning that when the remote user connects and wants to start another program as administrator, they hear the prompt sound, but can't actually see the dialog nor interact with it. If the local user then clicks yes, they can see the dialog that comes after it, but cannot interact with it in any way.

If yes was clicked, they can see and do all that.

In this case, the program TeamViewer does not actually write to a file or registry at all.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not know what specific changes an app will make; only that the app needs access to the registry to make changes and updates as well as access to Program Files to install and change software files.

Many apps I use (Office, Adobe, VMware and so on) have a "What's new or like facility to inform us of changes. Many times for a major update, the list of changes is 2 or 3 pages.

We have to look at "What's new" ourselves to know what changes to expect. Sometimes (some apps), I get an email from the software vendor saying here is what is new and here is an update link. Windows still says "Your app will make changes"

I get the same kind of thing from Ubuntu and Kali requiring admin credentials to install software and updates.

So no, "this app will make changes" does not provide a list at that point. That is the app responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea what an MSI installer will do by examining it in ORCA.
More info on ORCA here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe

But knowing that an installer will install MYSTERYXXX.DLL will not necessarily be enlightening. There may be no way to tell what MYSTERYXXX.DLL actually does. The same is true of any EXE and other files that get installed.

IMO, you're probably better off researching the app you plan to install, google things like "appname problems", "appname bugs" and so on.